# How can I make this function open a new tab in my actual browser on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, tkinter, browser, operating-system

I just started learning software development with GUI elements and so far I have managed to come up with this program, that the only thing it does is to create a GUI element that has a button which opens a new chrome window when clicked:

```
import tkinter as tk #
import subprocess
import os
import sys

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
root.title("Bulk upload to OpenSea")

main_directory = os.path.join(sys.path[0])
def open_chrome_profile():
    subprocess.Popen(
        [
            "start",
            "chrome",
            "--remote-debugging-port=8989",
            "--user-data-dir=" + main_directory + "/chrome_profile",
        ],
        shell=True,
    )

#####BUTTON ZONE#######
open_browser = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Open Chrome Browser", command=open_chrome_profile)
open_browser.grid(row=22, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

**GUI preview:**

[image: preview1]

**Result after clicking the "Open Chrome Browser" button:**
[image: preview2]

However, I noticed that the chrome browser deployed is not the real one I use, I know that it uses the statement `"--user-data-dir=" + main_directory + "/chrome_profile"` to deploy a driver-like version of my browser, but I don't know how could I get the corresponding path (and its profile) to my actual chrome browser.

How should the function `open_chrome_profile()` be changed in order to open a new tab in my actual chrome browser?

Comment: Is this a user specific option? Do you want to ALWAYS open chrome? Why not the default browser of the user?

Comment: Well, actually the default browser would work as well, but I don't know how to call it neither @CoolCloud

Comment: Try using `webbrowser` module: `webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://google.com')`.

Comment: BINGO! That's exactly what I needed! can you post it as an answer to give you the check ✔️ ? @acw1668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `webbrowser` module:

```py
webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://google.com')
```